# React Native Android Module call library during Application onCreate

Tags: android, react-native

I have written a React Native module to access a Bluetooth device. The device has its own SDKs for Android and iOS. In Android, a specific SDK function needs to be called during the Android Application onCreate method.

What is the correct way to call this functionality from the parent app? Do I create a method in the library module that the parent app can call or do I import the JAR dependency that the library module uses and just call the needed onCreate function of the SDK directly from the parent?

At first, I tried calling it from the library module constructor, but the SDK needs an application object, not an application context.

Here is the relevant portion of the module:

```
public MyLibraryModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    super(reactContext);
    this.reactContext = reactContext;
    SomeBluetoothManager.onApplicationCreate(reactContext);
}
```

Since I need to call the `onApplicationCreate` method of the dependent SDK during `onCreate` I tried importing the library directly in the parent app:

```
import com.something.SomeBluetoothManager;
```

And then in the `MainApplication.java` of the React Native android app:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SomeBluetoothManager.onApplicationCreate(this);
}
```

This fails to find the import for the Bluetooth manager class. Is the parent React Native app supposed to automatically include and make available any libs from the native library module so that I can import them in the Application?

I have the Bluetooth SDK jar file and dependent .so files in a folder called libs and added this to the relevant part of the module `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
    ...
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }
}
```

My last thought since the import didn't find the child library to import was to create a static method either in the library module class or the library package class:

```
public static void onCreate(Application app) {
    SomeBluetoothManager.onApplicationCreate(app);
}
```

If I add this static call to the application `onCreate` override method the app just crashes on launch:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    MyLibraryPackage.onCreate(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain the application context from the ReactApplicationContext and then cast the application context to a type of Application:

```
Application app = (Application)reactContext.getApplicationContext();
SomeBluetoothManager.onApplicationCreate(app);
```

This appears to have gotten me past my hurdle with this particular Bluetooth library.

Comment: Where did you call this from your code though? I need to do something similar and I want to call it once when the app is created